# Matplotlib stopped working after upgrade to 1.1.0

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to run matplotlib 1.1.0 under Ubuntu 11.10. I previously had matplotlib 1.0.1 installed and working, but I needed some features from version 1.1.0 (and was becoming quite annoyed that all the documentation was for another version than mine) so I decided to upgrade.

Now, I can't show any plots.

I have uninstalled everything I had from the package repository, and [installed version 1.1.0 from source](http://matplotlib.github.com/users/installing.html#installing-from-source). I've read through the [installation FAQ](http://matplotlib.github.com/faq/installing_faq.html#matplotlib-compiled-fine-but-nothing-shows-up-with-plot) but the hints there did not help. I get the following output from their suggested troubleshooting procedure, but no plot:

```
$HOME=/home/tomas
CONFIGDIR=/home/tomas/.matplotlib
matplotlib data path /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
loaded rc file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
matplotlib version 1.1.0
verbose.level helpful
interactive is False
platform is linux2
Using fontManager instance from /home/tomas/.matplotlib/fontList.cache
backend agg version v2.2
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

**Update:**
After following up on some troubleshooting tips in comments, I can report that it's the actual *showing* of plots that doesn't work.

Running the following script outputs a png with the expected plot, but does not show any plotting window.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.savefig('testfig.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it give you any sort of error message?

Comment: @ThomasK: Nope, it just silently fails to show any plots.

Comment: Did you remove the older version before installing the new one?

Comment: have you tried different backends? Can you write the plot to a file using `plt.savefig('test.pdf')`?

Comment: @Zhenya: Yes, I did. I unstalled using `sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib` and also did a `find / -ipath "*matplotlib*"` and deleted anything that wasn't installation files for 1.1.0 before installing from source. It did not help.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: Nice catch! `savefig('testfig.png')` does indeed output a png file which I can open with `eog`, and it looks as I expected. So it's the actual *showing* of plots that doesn't work...

Comment: @TomasLycken: I know it's going to sound crazy, but nonetheless--- did you try installing it from source on a clean 11.10? What I'm suspecting is that by cleaning up you've deleted something relevant. --- On 10.04 compiling from source works fine if you just `sudo apt-get remove python-matplolib`.

Comment: @Zhenya: I haven't tried that (installing on a clean 11.10), but unfortunately I don't really have a good way to test if it works - reinstalling my system isn't really an option and I don't have another one to test it on.

Answer (score 3):

When you import `pyplot`, it has to set a backend, and it may be setting it to a non-interactive one, which would explain the behavior you are seeing. See what backend is being used by running `plt.get_backend()`

To set the backend, you have to run these commands  *before* importing `pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use(your_backend)
```

where

```
your_backend in set(["FLTKAgg", "GTK", "GTKAgg", "GTKCairo", "macosx",
                    "QTAgg", "QT4Agg", "TkAgg", "WX", "WXAgg"])
```

To make this a permanent setting, put the backend name (without quotes) in your `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file, like this example:

```
backend       : WXAgg
```